# How to retrieve "state" param from the oauth response in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using spring boot, specifically [spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client/3.0.2) dependency for google login. Everything is working fine except that I need to send some details in the request and then retrieve them back from the response so that I can use those details. I did some research and found that I can do that by using **state** parameter while sending the Oauth Request. I can successfully set the "state" value in my custom OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver as below:

```
private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest customizeAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest req,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        String state = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("test".getBytes());
        return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(req).state(state).build();

    }
```

This is all working fine! However, I'm not sure how to retrieve this value from the response. I can see there is `OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java` which is doing all the magic of creating the user after the authentication. I thought I could somehow override it and get the state value but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I'm also thinking there maybe an easier way. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done by default.
It seems that state parameter in this implementation is only used for csrf, it is not intented to be used to pass custom data as well with it.

Problem is that they doesn't offer customization for class OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider where state is compared between request and response in authenticate method. So we can't access the step where we get response back to redirect uri.

We would need addition to this implementation where we can customize OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider or we would get state from user attributes. We have there e.g. nonce attribute. We could also use nonce to pass custom data with it, but we can't set nonce by default.
We can set state, but we can't read it afterwards. We can't set nonce but we can read it afterwards.
Before we get update which allows easy access to state parameter we need to customize the implementation, which of course is not recommended.